# Monitor mode in Kali Linux not working

Tags: networking, kali-linux, airmon-ng

when I try to use the command `airmon-ng` I get back as an answer: `ls: cannot access '/sys/class/ieee80211/': no such file or directory`. Nothing is wrong with normal network, I am writing from Kali system.
Thanks

PS: I am in Virtual Machine, and am using VirtualBox.

Answer (score -1):

According to [the VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html), the following (virtual) network adapters are implemented:

- AMD PCNet PCI II (Am79C970A)
- AMD PCNet FAST III (Am79C973, the default)
- Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)
- Intel PRO/1000 T Server (82543GC)
- Intel PRO/1000 MT Server (82545EM)
- Paravirtualized network adapter (virtio-net)

None of these are wireless adapters so therefore your virtual machine will never see any of the 802.11 features. Additionally, even if VirtualBox did implement a wireless network card, it would never see any signals because it's not attached to a real radio.

In theory, you could get a virtual machine to see a wireless card through [PCI or USB passthrough](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html), but I have never tried that so cannot give an opinion about how well that works.

Comment: So I can't enable monitor mode? I could only enable it if I was on a real PC with Kali installed?

Comment: You won't be able to do anything wireless-related inside a virtual machine, correct. As to the other question, that's a completely different question, and one that I cannot answer as I've never used Kali before. I would recommend checking with the [Kali forum](http://forums.kali.org/) for more assistance.